# Scene do not go to Full Screen

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a strange problem. I searched a lot and did every patch which came in front of me, still getting no result.

My Problem is In JavaFx when i run my program it runs successfully in fullscreen mode. But when exit from full screen and then again if want to toggle to fullscreen on button click. The application do not go to full screen. Even i get the specific message like "Press ESC to exit full screen" but application is not in fullscreen.

This is the code i have written.

```
@FXML
public void gotoFullScreen(){
    Stage stage = (Stage) contentPane.getScene().getWindow();
    System.out.println(stage.getTitle()); // I'm getting stage title this means stage is not null
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
}
```

This is the Image

[image]

Even i did like this

```
@FXML
public void gotoFullScreen(){
    Stage stage = (Stage) contentPane.getScene().getWindow();
    System.out.println(stage.getTitle()); // I'm getting stage title this means stage is not null
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.show();
}
```

Still it does not go to Full Screen.

Comment: If you call `setFullScreen` on the correct `Stage`, it should go to full screen.

Comment: I did call it on current stage. As you can see the message in the image i have posted

Comment: After having copied and pasted your exact code i found it worked completely on windows and ubuntu...can i ask what operating system you are using, it may be a driver issue if you are using a certain linux distro? - specifically iv had this problem occur when using antergos os due to lack of support for amd graphics card drivers however i may be wrong but the code above does work as id have expected.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with gnome session fallback. I will try it on unity. may it's because of that classic desktop I'm using.

Comment: It may help to test on a few platforms I find vms the best for these types of problems but Yeh the full screen command in a few development platforms I have tried failed on various Linux distributions so is always worth it to test both the operating system, graphics drivers and maybe even the current version of javafx/java on that particular platform, hope it works out